# Вернуть разные значения в зависимости от значения в исходной ячейке

Tags: excel

В зависимости от значения в исходной ячейке надо подставить в другую ячейку определённые значения.

Например:

```
если A1=0, то A2=80
если A1=1, то A2=90
если A1=2, то А2=550
и т.п.
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Есть ли система в значениях, или они с потолка?

Comment: не подскажете закономерность? на трёх значениях её не видно. линейная не подходит.

Comment: понимаете есть таблица ей каждой цифре принадлежит свой код допустим 1 принадлежит 80 а 2 к примеру 10000 нету закономерности!

Comment: @Никита Куцур, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вас спасёт функция [VLOOKUP](http://www.planetaexcel.ru/tip.php?aid=26) (по ссылке подробное описание с примером).

Answer (score 2):

По таким ограниченным данным нельзя предложить оптимальное решение. Если набор пар большой, то предложенная ранее *ВПР()* - самое оно.

Возможно, в изменении данных можно нащупать алгоритм. В таком случае решение может быть совсем неожиданным.

Несколько формул, решающие задачу, описанную в первом авторском сообщении:

```
=ПРОСМОТР(A1;{0;1;2};{80;90;550})
=ВПР(A1;{0;80:1;90:2;550};2)
=ВЫБОР(A1+1;80;90;550)
=НАИМЕНЬШИЙ({80;90;550};A1+1)
```